# PyImport_Import return null when import pyodbc

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.6

I use the python example from https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html.

every thing is right until I added one line `import pyodbc` in the 'multiply.py' file. `PyImport_Import` will return `null` if i add this line,and `PyErr_Print()` show that `no module named pyodbc`.
but actually, i have install `pyodbc` with pip,and i run 'multiply.py' with no problem on command line.

Is something wrong?

Comment: window 7,python 3.6.5

Comment: Check your PYTHONPATH if it leads to the location where pyobc is installed.

Comment: pyodbc is installed in 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd'. I use 'PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)")' in the C++ program to show the PYTHONPATH,it shows that 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages',with a 'Lib'replaced by 'lib'.

Comment: Actually,there's no folder named 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib'.I have no idea why it can be executed directly but can't be excuted by C++ program.

Comment: The multiply.py can be imported in python 3.6.5 shell with no problem.I use sys.path ['', 'E:\\Lee\\ShowRoom\\毒麻柜\\毒麻柜软件\\毒麻柜各模块\\NarcoticModule\\Debug', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: ok, in that case I would recommend installing everything again. or wait until somebody else response to your question, because your problem is very strange and I can't explain it....

Comment: Thank you,I will reinstall python and try again.

Comment: I reinstall python,and this problem is fixed,thanks a lot. even though the PYTHONPATH is still replaced by 'lib',anyway,my C++ program can work properly.

Comment: Nice happy to help.  I made a quick answer out of my comment, could you please mark is as correct. So that everybody sees that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend installing everything again, because your problem is very strange and I nobody was able to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `PYTHON_PATH` variable to your working directory in the system path 
Add `PYTHON_HOME` variable if not exist and add the python scripts folder as well.